Does Tcl or Expect have the ability to quote arguments in a way that is parsable by a shell?
Consider the following short Expect program:
#!/usr/bin/expect

puts $::argc
puts $::argv

If I invoke it as follows, it correctly identifies that there are four elements, but the natural tcl representation of the argv array is not directly passable to a shell.
./Test.exp x y z "a b c"
4
x y z {a b c}

Is it possible to force TCL to output the arguments in a shell-friendly way so that I could pass them to another program via send?
Just to be explicit, I know I can directly pass the arguments to spawn or exec.
However, I would like to know if it is feasible to send the arguments to a spawned shell (e.g, bash), which requires correct shell quoting.
This is useful for sending a sequence of commands to bash using arguments passed to the expect script and being able to log the whole pseudo-interactive session.

You do realize you can exec a shell, sending the arguments out of band from the code to execute?

Yes, I realize that, as I pointed out in the question.

Not sure, but this question might be what you need.

Nope, I already saw that one.
I'm aware of the exec solution and this question is focused specifically on shell quoting.

You said you knew you could exec a shell. That doesn't mean you knew you could address extra arguments from that shell.

That is a fair point! To be concrete, I know what I can exec a shell and pass in arguments as a tcl list as well use bash -c 'full_shell_command_line' from tcl.
If there is something else you're referring to, I'd love to learn from you!

bash -c 'script that uses "$1" "$2" etc' 'value for $0' 'value for $1' ... -- if that's what you're referring re arguments as a tcl list, then you're indeed already well-informed.

Yes, I know I can do that. Thanks for double-checking though!

The lazy way is to use bash itself to do the escaping. That way you don't have to account for every special character and edge case that can come up; the shell already knows about them and can handle them for you.
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

# Take a list and return a single string with the elements of that list
# escaped in a way that bash can split back up into individual elements
proc quote_args {raw} {
    string map {"\n" " "} [exec bash -c {printf "%q\n" "$@"} bash {*}$raw]
}

# Demonstrate usage by calling a shell with a single argument including the
# escaped arguments
set quoted_argv [quote_args $argv]
puts "Escaped: $quoted_argv"
puts [exec bash -c "printf \">%s<\\n\" $quoted_argv"]

Example usage:
$ ./args.tcl x y z "a b c"
Escaped: x y z a\ b\ c
>x<
>y<
>z<
>a b c<
$ ./args.tcl x y z $'a b\nc' # Works with embedded newlines
Escaped: x y z $'a b\nc'
>x<
>y<
>z<
>a b
c<
$ ./args.tcl 'a b$c' # And things that look like shell parameters that shouldn't be substituted
Escaped: a\ b\$c
>a b$c<


This is the most robust solution, as far as I can tell.
Today I learned about printf '%q'!

For going the other way, tcllib has a package for breaking up a string with shell quotes (But only sh, no extensions like bash's ansi-quotes).

Safer to NUL delimit than newline delimit. %q will often choose to escape newlines into $'\n' sequences, but that's not outright guaranteed.

@CharlesDuffy Looking at the bash source, I don't see how it won't escape a newline. But switching to nul is trivial if needed.

To be clear, I meant guaranteed by spec, vs implementation -- make a design decision based on one specific version and you only have guaranteed correctness for that one specific version. (I have seen content generated with literal newlines in single quotes, but that could have been ksh or zsh rather than bash, or a version of bash that's no longer current).

NUL-delimited is much safer, but most shell commands don't cope so well with it. If I really need robust handling of arbitrary strings, I prefer to not have the shell involved at all; Tcl (along with several other languages) is far superior at not mangling things.

I ended up implementing my own version while waiting for other answers, so I am posting for completeness, since the end result looks a little different from the others.
#!/usr/bin/expect

puts $::argc
puts $::argv

# tcl 8.5 does not have lmap, so this implementation is placed here.
proc map {fun list} {
  set res {}
  foreach element $list {lappend res [$fun $element]}
  set res
}

# Turn an individual argument into a string that the shell likes.
proc transformArg {arg} {
  if {[string first "'" $arg] == -1} {
    return "'$arg'"
  }
  proc wrapInSingleQuote {x} {return "'$x'"}
  return [join [map wrapInSingleQuote [split $arg {'}] ] {"'"}]
}

foreach arg $::argv {
  lappend changedArg [transformArg $arg]
}
puts [join "$changedArg" " "]


The string to be ouput needs to be consrtucted:
#!/usr/bin/expect
set output {}
foreach arg $argv {
    set escaped_arg [string map {"\\" "\\\\" "\"" "\\\""} $arg]
    if {[regexp { } $escaped_arg] || [regexp {'} $escaped_arg]} {
        lappend output "\"$escaped_arg\""
    } else {
        lappend output $escaped_arg
    }
}
puts $argc
puts [join $output " "]


Also need to escape tabs, $, and possibly other characters.
